# Best search algorithem for (black box) system with two parameters. Fuzzy Logic?

Tags: algorithm, search

A system with unknown function f(x,y)=z , x and y are inputs and z is the yield or output.

X: is a real number ranges from (1.01 to 2.99), step 0.01
Y: is integer number ranges from (1-to 100)
Z: a real number represents yields , the more the better.

Changing x and y values yields different Z value ( X and Y has some unknown correlation),but we always get same Z with the same X and Y.

Task: Find optimal X and Y combination to get probably the best possible yield at the output (Z) . For example: X = 2.23, Y = 87 gives probably best possible yield Z=5.15.

is there any other algorithm to search optimal X and Y apart from Brute-force?

Edit:

-Is there an algorithm to learn( discover a bias of some sort ) the correlation between X and Y? so that examining next set 
of data will have systematic advantage based on first experience
- Can Fuzzy Logic be applied here ?

Comment: Well, there are only 200*100 possible values, brute force will get a quick 100% accurate answer. I see no reason to further optimize it (unless this is done in a tight loop of course, or might need higher scales later on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there are only 200*100 possible values, brute force will get a quick 100% accurate answer. I see no reason to further optimize it (unless this is done in a tight loop of course, or might need higher scales later on)

However, if your problem might scale higher, and since we are discussing "probably maximal" (and not definetly maximal) values, one approach could be to sample the data at certain points, and do a **[polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) to approximate how the data behaves** in this range.

Assuming there is some rational behind it (which might or might not be) - you will get a curve which is a close approximation to your data.

After it - use general methods (derivitives) to find local maximums (and from this the global maximum).

While this is not 100% accurate, it will get you close to the maximal value, assuming there is rational behind the seperation of the data.

Comment: Would you give an example of "general methods (derivatives)"?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know *something* more about the function, it's not possible to do better than checking every value.

Considering something like this: (just taking `x` as a parameter - drawing in 3D is a little more difficult - but the same applies to 2 parameters) (assuming a higher value of `z` is better)

[image]

There's no way to predict whether there will be some jump in the function, as indicated above, or where it will occur.

Or there could be much less continuity:

[image]

**If you just want a decent value for `z`, not necessarily the optimal:**

You can just check a few values (either randomly, along some increment, e.g. checking 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc., or with some other method) and hope to get a decent value for `z`.

But, because of the cases shown above, there's no guarantee - you may end up with values much, much worse than the optimal.

Comment: I don't like this answer, he asks for "probably optimal", while you aim to show a 100% answer is not possible.

Comment: @amit Edited... (although probably not much better)

Answer (score 0):

If  there aren't any additional information about the function `f`, e.g. `smooth function`, only brute-force can found a solution. And it will 100% right solution.

Any other attempts not better than random choise X and Y, because will not give any warranty.

Therefore, if the time for you to find a solution is more important than its validity, the optimal solution would be a random selection of X and Y.